# Moving SSL certificate to another Apache server

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, apache-2.2, openssl, mod-ssl

We just setup new Windows machine as a web server, with **Apache 2.2.19 with openssl** installed and we want to move our existing web including the SSL certificate (Verisign) from the old setup, **Linux, Apache 2.2.3**.

Now, if I search online, all I can find is to copy and paste the cert files to the new server. But when I have done all the configurations, Apache failed to start with nothing printed in error log, only a prompt saying **The Requested Operation has failed**.

I tried to run `httpd.exe -e debug` and saw it stopped on `Loaded module ssl_module` and these lines printed in the error.log:

```
[Thu Aug 18 18:18:18 2011] [info] Init: Initialized OpenSSL library
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

And from Windows event viewer:

```
Faulting application httpd.exe, version 2.2.19.0, time stamp 0x4dd6eda8, 
faulting module libapr-1.dll, version 1.4.5.0, time stamp 0x4dd6ed65, 
exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0000fc39, process id 0xe08, 
application start time 0x01cc5b07b33b8a60.
```

I'm sure that I configured the path to crt files correctly, since this is what I get if I tried to put a wrong path:

```
[Thu Aug 18 18:13:35 2011] [debug] mod_so.c(246): loaded module ssl_module
Syntax error on line 133 of C:/Apache2.2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf: 
   SSLCACertificateFile: file 'C:/Apache2.2/conf/ssla/intermediate.crt' 
   does not exist or is empty
```

Apache runs perfectly if I use a self signed certificate. What might be gone wrong?

**UPDATE**

Checking using openssl verify command as @polynomial suggested in his answer:

```
> openssl verify /path/to/file.pem
> error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

`openssl version -d` shows that `OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"`

Does **OPENSSLDIR** caused the error? If yes, how do I solve this?

Comment: Can you please search for "faulty module path" in your logs or event viewer and paste the error?

Comment: I couldn't find the text "faulty" on event viewer or apache error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved.

The problem was that the pass-phrase file was written for linux so it didn't run on windows.

We also updated the cert files to use Windows line-endings but i'm not sure if that had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps the certificate you have is munged or the OpenSSL install on your windows box is having a hard time understanding it for some reason.  If you try to verify the certificate or extract information from it using the openssl command line on your windows box does it work?

Some command info:

http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#verify-standard

Specifically check:

```
openssl verify /path/to/file.pem
openssl x509 -text -in /path/to/cert.pem
```

Comment: checking with `openssl verify` returns `error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate`, `openssl version -d` shows `OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"`, does this mean the OPENSSLDIR is the cause? How do I solve this?

Comment: **upate** I just check on the old server, running openssl verify on the cert also give `unable to get local issuer certificate`

Answer (score -3):

SSL certificates are generated for a specific server at a specific address, you can't just copy them from one server to another [even if the IP address is the same]

Your paths and setup is probably correct [hence your self signed cert working]. What you need to do is generate a new CSR, contact your SSL certificate provider and have a new certificate issued, generlly you would not have to pay for that.

-sean

Comment: Yes, I have generated a new CSR and going to pass it to client since they are the one who have the account. But, doesn't this mean all the tutorials and guides on the internet are wrong? It said we can just copy the cert files.

Comment: Can you point us to one of those tutorials that say you can copy a cert from one server to another? I admit I don't know it all, but in my experience this is not possible.

Comment: It's actually quite easy to find one, from Verisign: [Move or Export a certificate](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=AR218) Another question is, if you say that this is not possible, how do you manage with load balanced servers?

Comment: "If these remain identical, you can export (back-up) the certificate and its private key from the original server and import (move) it into the target server." - from verisign. Now, someone else is gonna have to jump in here, but moving private keys from server to server? I think this is assuming a single server situation?

Comment: Also I believe that on a windows server that machine ID thing has something to do with generating it's keys... however that is a blind guess.

Comment: Most SSL certificates do not contain any information specific to the server they are used on.  Only the DNS names used in securing the connection.  You can move them between servers easily, this is required for any load balanced installations like previously mentioned.

Comment: I'll just chime in here as someone who runs the same certificate on multiple load balanced servers, and who moves them around fairly frequently as necessary. This answer is very wrong.